# Ayuda por favor, el browsersync no me recarga automaticamente

Tags: web, navegador-web

Estoy tratando de sincronizar mi navegador con browsersync con el comando (browser-sync start --server --directory --files "*") pero tengo el problema de que mi navegador no se recarga automáticamente cuando hago un cambio en mis archivos, los cambios solo se manifiestan cuando le doy recargar y la idea es que sean automáticos.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, estas en el sitio en español por favor traduce tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

intenta

```
browser-sync start --server --files "./*.css"
```

esto agarra todos los archivos css que tengas, claro esta que una ves modificado el archivo dar ctrl+S para ver si aparece algún cambio

Comment: y si tengo archivos html y js también los agarra? o cual sería el comando para incluir estos archivos html y js?

Comment: browser-sync start --server --files "./*.*"   este seria el comando para agarre todo lo que tengas

Comment: ya ejecuté el comando que me recomendaste y cada vez que hago un cambio en mis archivos, la terminal me dice que se estan recargando los navegadores, pero cuando voy a los navegadores no se cargan automaticamente sino que tengo que darle recargar para que se vean los cambios que hice.

Comment: cuando creo el server o el proxy no me refrescaba antes el navegador, después de darle mucho tiempo cuando lo utilizaba me di con la solución y ---puede ser algo como poner una , o un ; ---- y la solución en dado caso que les pase es que no se olviden de crear la estructura html ya sea un html o un php porque browser-sync necesita saber donde insertar el script con el que va a hacer la inyección de código pero yo se que lo debes de tener, la otra opción seria volverlo a instalar jaja y pon index.html si es que no lo tienes asi aveces se pone los moños

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, voy a intentar lo que me dices a ver si doy con la solución.